# How do you unlock people in Tekken Revolution?

Tags: tekken

How do I unlock new characters? I want Eliza, Nina, Dragunov, and Bob? How do I unlock these people? Would it be free? I have 10915 gift points, and 60 blood seals.

Answer (score 1):

When you have 30 000 gist points you get new random character